# "Error: no such partition" after uninstalling Ubuntu

Tags: grub2, windows-7, grubrescue

I had Ubuntu installed on dual boot with Windows 7. I decided that I liked it, but I did not want the dual boot option, so I uninstall it. Now whenever I turn on my computer, it skips BIOS and goes directly to the "error: no such partition" screen then I can't do anything at all.

I tried restarting it and booting from a Windows recovery disc to fix the MBR, but my BIOS no won't load, I can't change the boot order, and I can't manually boot or anything. It just goes straight to the "error: no such partition" screen.

I even tried putting in the Ubuntu disc which I installed from, and nothing happens. I can't access BIOS or anything at all.

Comment: even tried putting in the ubuntu disc i installed from, and nothing happens. cant access bios or anything at all.

Comment: You have to configure how to boot from the CD/DVD of Windows and fix the MBR. Ubuntu has nothing to do with your problem. You uninstalled Ubuntu wrong way. FIRST you do an MBR fix from Windows CD/DVD (so you can be sure that PC boots straight into Windows) and after that you can delete the partitions with Ubuntu (via Windows disk manager)

Comment: i cant do anything on my computer....it skips bios wont boot from cd wont do anything. it goes straight to "error: no such partition screen"